# open jpeg with win32 api c++

Tags: c++, api, winapi

i've a simple dialog created with ResEdit

```
BOOL CALLBACK AppDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg)
  {

  case WM_INITDIALOG:
    SetClassLongPtr(hDlg, GCLP_HICON, (long)LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION));
    return 1;
  case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(wParam)
    {
    case IDOK:
      return 0;
    case IDCANCEL:
      EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
    }
     switch(wParam)
            {
                 case IDC_BUTTON1:
                    MessageBox(hDlg, "Hello, World!", "Bottone premuto", MB_OK);
                break;
            }


  }
  return 0;
}
```

i want to know if there's a way to push a button and display a JPG image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
ShellExecute(NULL,
             "open",
             "C:\\path\\to\\jpg\\my.jpg",
             NULL,
             NULL,
             SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Comment: another question, can i load that image in a "picture control" (as ResEdit call it) or anyway in the window i created? 
thank you!!!!